# Java 7 : compilation time double (mac osx)

Tags: java, performance, macos

We have just upgraded some mac used as continuous integration server from Java 6 to Java  7 (compiling in java 6 though for the time being) : our compilation time has doubled !!

Is it "normal" ? Can it be tweaked somehow ?

I didn't manage to find meaningful resources on the topic, so if ever you know something about it please let me know !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you please say if you use some frameworks or some particular packages more often in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Is Java 6 removed from the machine? It could be your tomcat (or whatever you are using) is still running on Java 6, and when you compiled using Java 6, it was faster because [Class Data Sharing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/class-data-sharing.html) was kicking in. This will not work when different Java versions are used.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Axel but the logs are all pointing to Java 7... :(